# How do you embed the Wordpress Categories widget in a page/post outside the sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

Rather than use another widget I want to code the method to include the WP "Categories" widget directly within the content of a page or post.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add wordpress post categories into the template file you need to use

```
<?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
```

Default arguments are :

```
<?php  $args = array(
      'show_option_all'    => ,
      'orderby'            => 'name',
      'order'              => 'ASC',
      'show_last_update'   => 0,
      'style'              => 'list',
      'show_count'         => 0,
      'hide_empty'         => 1,
      'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
      'child_of'           => 0,
      'feed'               => ,
      'feed_type'          => ,
      'feed_image'         => ,
      'exclude'            => ,
      'exclude_tree'       => ,
      'include'            => ,
      'hierarchical'       => true,
      'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
      'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'),
      'number'             => NULL,
      'echo'               => 1,
      'depth'              => 0,
      'current_category'   => 0,
      'pad_counts'         => 0,
      'taxonomy'           => 'category',
      'walker'             => 'Walker_Category' );
 ?>
```

or you can simply use it without parameters, in that case defaults will work.

```
 <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
```

you can read more about this function [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a plugin called [Widgets on Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-on-pages/) and then just drag Categories into the newly created "sidebar" - then you just put the shortcode [widgets_on_pages] anywhere you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you search for this.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36511/are-widgets-meant-to-be-used-outside-of-sidebars